# How do I scrape lyrics from a list of song lyric urls?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Currently I have a list of 500 urls called "urls" in python that lead to song lyrics and I'm wondering how I can scrape the lyrics of each song from its corresponding url. I assume I have to create a for loop with BeautifulSoup but I'm not sure how to approach it. Below shows how I got the list of urls from a csv.

```
path = os.path.join('c:' + os.sep, 'Users', '....', 'Downloads', 'dataset_6.csv')
   data = pd.read_csv(path, header = 0)
   data.columns = data.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
   urls = list(data.lyricsurl)
   print(urls)
```

Here's what the first item in the list looks like along with every other url:

```
['https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/natkingcole/sweetlorraine.html', '...', '...']
```

This is the class in which the lyrics fall under in the html documents

```
class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 text-center"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do all the URLs point to the same website format, i.e. azlyrics? Seems to me, you'd want to write code to download 1 lyric page. Then add a loop. If you don't have the first part working without a loop yet, please work on or ask about that part before worrying about the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This example will loop over all urls in the list and print the lyrics:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls = [
    "https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/natkingcole/sweetlorraine.html",
    # ...more urls
]

for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    lyric = soup.select_one(".ringtone ~ div").get_text(
        strip=True, separator="\n"
    )

    print(lyric)
```

Prints:

```
Just found joy
I'm as happy as a baby boy, baby boy
With another brand new choo-choo choy
When I met my sweet Lorraine, Lorraine, Lorraine.

...and so on.
```